# Python tkinter delete event.widget.create_line

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I have written a simple paint program and I'm having trouble with a task. I want to be able to delete/remove lines that have been drawn. When ButtonPress-1 is down is creates a line until ButtonRelease-1 is triggered (ButtonPress-1 is up). When pressing the 'Reset' button I want the line to be deleted/removed. I currently have it so when I press 'Reset' the program restarts itself, which is a bad solution.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import sys
import os
import subprocess

b1 = "up"
xold, yold = None, None
color= "black"
linesize = 2

def main():
    global root
    root = Tk()
    global drawing_area
    drawing_area = Canvas(root, width=1050, height=1200, background="white")
    drawing_area.pack()
    drawing_area.bind("<Motion>", motion)
    drawing_area.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", b1down)
    drawing_area.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", b1up)

    button1 = Button(root, text = "Reset", command = restart_program, anchor = N)
    button1.configure(width = 3, background = "#FFFFFF", relief = FLAT)
    button1_window = drawing_area.create_window(640, 0, anchor=N, window=button1)

    root.geometry('1050x1200')
    root.geometry('+0+720')
    root.mainloop()

def restart_program():
    python = sys.executable
    os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)

def b1down(event):
    global b1
    b1 = "down"

def b1up(event):
    global b1, xold, yold
    b1 = "up"
    xold = None
    yold = None

def motion(event):
    if b1 == "down":
        global xold, yold
        if xold is not None and yold is not None:
            event.widget.create_line(xold,yold,event.x,event.y,smooth=TRUE,fill = color, width=linesize)
        xold = event.x
        yold = event.y

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want it to delete all items on the canvas you can call canvas.delete("all")
Or you can create the lines with a tag, and then delete by tag

so you could change:

```
event.widget.create_line(xold,yold,event.x,event.y,smooth=TRUE,fill = color, width=linesize)
```

to:

```
event.widget.create_line(xold,yold,event.x,event.y,smooth=TRUE,fill = color, width=linesize, tag="line")
```

and then call:
canvas.delete("line")

this will delete all items with that tag.

EDIT:
further to the origional request here is a code sample that allows simple undo/redo functions, note the following drawbacks:

1. as you undo more items the stored list will grow continually, it is not limited to any set size
2. if you undo an item and then draw a new item manually, redo will still put back the removed line

   ```
   import Tkinter as tk
   import tkMessageBox
   import sys
   import os

   class App(tk.Tk):
       b1 = "up"
       xold, yold = None, None
       color= "black"
       linesize = 2
       counter = 1 #keeps track of the current working line, is incremented as soon as line is finished
       undone = [] #keeps a list of coordinate lists on undone items

       def __init__(self):
           tk.Tk.__init__(self)
           self.drawing_area = tk.Canvas(self, width=600, height=600, background="white")
           self.drawing_area.pack()
           self.drawing_area.bind("<Motion>", self.motion)
           self.drawing_area.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.b1down)
           self.drawing_area.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.b1up)

           self.button1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Reset", command = self.blank_canvas, anchor = tk.N)
           self.button1.configure(width = 3, background = "#FFFFFF", relief = tk.FLAT)
           self.button1.pack(side="left")

           self.button2 = tk.Button(self, text = "Undo", command = self.undo, anchor = tk.N)
           self.button2.configure(width = 3, background = "#FFFFFF", relief = tk.FLAT)
           self.button2.pack(side="left")

           self.button3 = tk.Button(self, text = "Redo", command = self.redo, anchor = tk.N)
           self.button3.configure(width = 3, background = "#FFFFFF", relief = tk.FLAT)
           self.button3.pack(side="left")

       def blank_canvas(self):
           self.drawing_area.delete("line")

       def undo(self):
           self.counter -= 1 #decrements the counter to look at the previous item
           currentlist = [] #creates a list to store the coordinates in
           for item in self.drawing_area.find_withtag("line"+str(self.counter)): #find all sub lines from the previous line
               currentlist.append(self.drawing_area.coords(item)) #get and add the coordinates to the working list
           self.drawing_area.delete("line"+str(self.counter)) #delete all items of the current line
           self.undone.append(currentlist) #add the working list to the stored list

       def redo(self):
           try:
               currentlist = self.undone.pop() #fetch and remove last set of coordinates
               for coords in currentlist: #for set of coordinates redraw subline
                   self.drawing_area.create_line(coords,smooth=tk.TRUE,fill = self.color, width=self.linesize, tags=["line", "line"+str(self.counter)])
               self.counter += 1 #re increment counter
           except IndexError:
               pass #occurs if list is empty

       def b1down(self, event):
           self.b1 = "down"

       def b1up(self, event):
           self.b1 = "up"
           self.xold = None
           self.yold = None
           self.counter += 1

       def motion(self, event):
           if self.b1 == "down":
               if self.xold is not None and self.yold is not None:
                   event.widget.create_line(self.xold,self.yold,event.x,event.y,smooth=tk.TRUE,fill = self.color, width=self.linesize, tags=["line", "line"+str(self.counter)])
               self.xold = event.x
               self.yold = event.y

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       app = App()
       app.mainloop()
   ```

Comment: Works perfectly, much obliged.

Comment: Hello again. I'm trying to also create a undo and redo function in this program as well. I tried the same method, as used here for delete, but it won't work. I can't find much documentation about it.
I've tried the same as above, but instead with the canvas.edit_undo("line") 'function'. You seem to have good knowledge about tkinter, maybe you could come with some tips.
Also you don't have to answer, but please leave a reply if you can or can't help me with this.

Comment: please see the amendments to my answer, hopefully this does what you're after.

Comment: Thank you so much, well done! It works perfectly after some tinkering (don't mind the pun, heh), the only problem I've stumbled up on is that it seems to break the "Clear" function. It stopped working after i added `+str(self.counter)` in the tag.  

I see you have changed the clear function here to clear everything on the canvas with `drawing_area.delete("all")`.
I just want to delete the lines as stated in the original question. That worked when I used `drawing_area.delete("line")`, but it seems like it has stopped working after I added counter to the tag variable.

Comment: to fix that you can create each line with multiple tags, so instead of tags="line"+str(self.counter), you could use tags=["line","line"+str(self.counter)] this gives it both tags, and then you can use canvas.delete("line") to only delete the lines, see my ammended answer

Comment: Oh, so you can have multiple tags, that's cool. Thanks!
Only problem with this is that I can't clear redone lines. But that's not too much of a trouble.

Comment: Maybe, the "Clear" function could flush the "memory" for undo/redo also. Thereby removing all traces of "lines".

Comment: A simple `counter = None` in the "Clear" function, will flush the memory for undo/redo but also breaks their functions. So that's not a solution.

Comment: Gaah, I'm sorry. I missed the tag for the redo function. It works as intended now.

Comment: if you wanted the clear function to wipe all undo/redo functions you should also reset the self.undone = [] so that the list of information is empty.

Comment: I figured that out and it works perfect. I'm satisfied with my program now. This is my first program written in Python. :)
You can check it out here if you want, https://github.com/HeadlessChild/pypaint-linux. Mind this program is developed for touch screens, like a kiosk.

Comment: overall i'd say it looks quite good however i would suggest a few things, if you code it as an object (using classes) you could lose all the global statements, and look into using radiobuttons for the colour chooser, you could drastically reduce the number of functions you need to use. see this: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/radiobutton.htm

Comment: Yes I'm aware of misuse of the global statements, but I just wanted to make something simple at the moment. In the future I will look more into a more object orientated type of programming. I've looked at radiobuttons but I want a more simple and "easy to use" colour chooser. Being a kiosk, the users just want a simple and easy way to use it. But yes it's quite ugly with that many functions.

Comment: well all i wast thinking is that if you used the radiobuttons with the indicatoron=0 argument you coult make something that looks functionally the same, but with less back end to maintain